# Trilogy about a boy who travelled to a ghost world through a mirror?

Tags: story-identification

I read this trilogy when I was around 12 and it was about this boy and his sister that moved to a city and they discovered this mirror that took them to a ghost city or something. There was 3 ghosts, a girl ghost who was mischievous, an older man ghost that I think was described like a pirate(?) who had a scar around his neck from where he hanged himself, and a young ghost boy who was mute.

I'm pretty sure the main characters name was Daniel(?) And there was a plot point about him being born on the witching hour or something...

I remember a specific scene where the ghost with the scar on his neck (I think his name was Jack(?) saved the main character's parents from crashing their car at some point. And another scene early on in the series where the mischievous girl was messing around in a restaurant and someone threw salt over their shoulder and she was annoyed by it.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)